# RSocket connection between .net and spring boot rsocket

Tags: java, .net, spring, spring-boot, rsocket

I try to send messages from .net service to sping boot service over RSocket protocol, connection is established but messages do not reach the destination. In both cases .net server - java client and java server - .net client.
Perhaps someone has already set up a working configuration (.net - spring boot over rsocket)

Working configuration for string messages (java server - .net client)

```
import io.rsocket.AbstractRSocket;
import io.rsocket.ConnectionSetupPayload;
import io.rsocket.DuplexConnection;
import io.rsocket.Payload;
import io.rsocket.RSocket;
import io.rsocket.RSocketFactory;
import io.rsocket.SocketAcceptor;
import io.rsocket.frame.decoder.PayloadDecoder;
import io.rsocket.transport.ServerTransport;
import io.rsocket.transport.netty.WebsocketDuplexConnection;
import io.rsocket.util.DefaultPayload;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;
import reactor.netty.Connection;
import reactor.netty.DisposableServer;
import reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer;

        ServerTransport.ConnectionAcceptor acceptor =
            RSocketFactory.receive()
                    .frameDecoder(PayloadDecoder.ZERO_COPY)
                    .acceptor(new SocketAcceptorImpl())
                    .toConnectionAcceptor();


    DisposableServer disposableServer =
            HttpServer.create()
                    .host("localhost")
                    .port(serverPort)
                    .route(
                            routes ->
                                    routes.ws(
                                            "/",
                                            (in, out) -> {
                                                DuplexConnection connection = new WebsocketDuplexConnection((Connection) in);
                                                return acceptor.apply(connection).then(out.neverComplete());
                                            }))
                    .bindNow();

class SocketAcceptorImpl implements SocketAcceptor {

    @Override
    public Mono<RSocket> accept(ConnectionSetupPayload setupPayload, RSocket reactiveSocket) {
        return Mono.just(
                new AbstractRSocket() {

                    @Override
                    public Mono<Void> fireAndForget(Payload payload) {
                        payload.release();
                        return Mono.empty();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Mono<Payload> requestResponse(Payload payload) {
                        return Mono.just(payload);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Flux<Payload> requestChannel(Publisher<Payload> payloads) {
                        return Flux.from(payloads).subscribeOn(Schedulers.single());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Flux<Payload> requestStream(Payload payload) {
                        String dataUtf8 = payload.getDataUtf8();
                        return Flux.just(DefaultPayload.create("!!! " + dataUtf8 + " !!!"));
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a `string` transport from RSocket net client to RSocket spring boot Java server try the answer set out at [rsocket net readerIndex exceeds writerIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66170385/rsocket-net-readerindex-exceeds-writerindex?noredirect=1&lq=1)